# How can I get matching records from multiple tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can I get records from tables that match at least in two tables? For example, all accounts that have same name. There can be many tables. PostgreSQL is used as a database.

In first table there are:

```
id   name
--------
11   acc1
12   acc4
13   acc5
14   acc9
15   acc10
16   acc1
17   acc1
18   acc4
19   acc10
```

In second table there are:

```
id   name
--------
21   acc4
22   acc6
23   acc8
24   acc10
```

In third table there are:

```
id   name
--------
31   acc1
32   acc7
33   acc9
34   acc8
35   acc10
```

And the result should be:

```
id-1  id-2  id-3
----------------
11    null  31
12    21    null
14    null  33
15    24    35
null  23    34
```

and ids in each column must be used only once and conditions might be more complex, for example, records should match by two fields.

Comment: get all the names and keep for each name the tables where it appears.  then see what names have more than 2 associated tables.  or simply keep a single counter for each name if the tables where it appear does not matter.

Comment: Can you explain the condition that prevents 19/24/35 ?

Comment: @GordonLinoff 24 and 35 already used in row 4 in result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want a `full join`:

```
select t1.id, t2.id, t3.id
from t1 full join
     t2
     using (name) full join
     t3
     using (name)
where ( (t1.id is not null)::int +
        (t2.id is not null)::int +
        (t3.id is not null)::int
      ) >= 2;
```

If you don't want duplicates, then you can do:

```
select t1.id, t2.id, t3.id
from (select name, min(id) as id from t1) t1 full join
     (select name, min(id) as id from t2) t2
     using (name) full join
     (select name, min(id) as id from t3) t3
     using (name)
where ( (t1.id is not null)::int +
        (t2.id is not null)::int +
        (t3.id is not null)::int
      ) >= 2;
```